# Randomly shuffling a mapping in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to randomly shuffle a mapping in Solidity. As I understand, this problem has 2 parts:

1. Generating a random number in a smart contract using a secure manner
2. Shuffling the mapping - **I'm more interested in this part**

To give you a clear scenario, I have a mapping of dogs, organized by IDs starting from 0. I have a function called `feedDog`, that is called using a dogID. After one person feeds the dog by calling the `feedDog` function, I want to somehow shuffle the IDs of the dog, so nobody knows who fed which dog.

```
struct Dog{
            string dogName;
            uint256 foodReceived; 
            uint256 dogID;
        }
    
    mapping(uint256 => Dog) private mappingOfDogs;
    
    function giveFood(uint256 dogID) public {
            mappingOfDogs[dogID].foodReceived++;  
            // random shuffling the mappingOfDogs occurs here, most likely
    
      
        }
```

***Output:***

1. Before the first call of `giveFood` function - Mapping of dogs: | 0.Charlie | 1.Copper | 2.Max |
2. After the first call of `giveFood` function - Mapping of dogs: | 0.Copper | 1.Max | 2.Charlie |
3. After the second call of `giveFood` function - Mapping of dogs: | 0.Charlie | 1.Max | 2. Copper |

I know that mappings aren't like arrays, but what if we retain the IDs in a separate array? Is there any way of doing this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

"so nobody knows who fed which dog" This won't be possible, there will always be a way of knowing which transaction changed which value on your contract, and because of that, people can see who submitted said transaction. Since Ethereum is a public blockchain, it's pretty difficult to "hide" stuff.

Aside from that, you can create a simple shuffle function for that.

```
function shuffle() internal {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
        uint256 n = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(randomNo))) % (numberArr.length - i) + i;

        String memory temp = dogs[n];
        dogs[n] = dogs[i];
        dogs[i] = temp;
    }
}
```